# How to get foreign key values with getattr from models

Tags: python, model, relational-database, callable, getattr

I have a model `Project` and i am getting the attributes of that with the following instr

```
attr = getattr(project, 'id', None)
```

`project` is the instance, `id` is the field and `None` is the default return type.

My question is: what if I want to get the Foreign Key keys with this?

### Get customer name

`project.customer.name` 
How to get customer name with the above condition?

### Already Tried

```
if callable(attr):
     context[node][field] = '%s' % attr()
```

### Current Code

```
context = {'project': {}}
fields = ('id', 'name', 'category', 'created_by', customer)

for field in fields:
    attr = getattr(project, field, None)
        if callable(attr):
            context['project'][field] = '%s' % attr()
        else:
            context['project'][field] = attr
```

i need to adjust customer object here. that i can give something like `customer__name` or `customer.name` in my fields and it get populated with the name of the customer, but i am not sure.

Comment: Why isn't `project.customer.name` cutting it?

Comment: well i want to use getattr to get customer name, i get customr object by this way. getattr(project, 'project.customer', None)
but i want something like his name
getattr(project, 'project.customer.name', None)

Comment: so `name = getattr(project.customer, 'name', None)` would work?

Comment: sure do, but i am writing a re-useable code something like that. let me edit the code above

Comment: Code updated @limelights

Comment: I'd think doing this would depending on what relational database you're using.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do something like follows:

```
def get_repr(value): 
    if callable(value):
        return '%s' % value()
    return value

def get_field(instance, field):
    field_path = field.split('.')
    attr = instance
    for elem in field_path:
        try:
            attr = getattr(attr, elem)
        except AttributeError:
            return None
    return attr

for field in fields:
    context['project'][field] = get_repr(get_field(project, field))
```

Comment: Perfect, although I'd change `attr = getattr(attr, elem)` to `attr = get_repr(getattr(attr, elem))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an equivalent recursive `getattr` -

```py
def get_foreign_key_attr(obj, field: str):
    """Get attr recursively by following foreign key relations

    For example ...
    get_foreign_key_attr(
        <Station: Spire operational 1m>, "idproject__idcountry__name"
    )
    ... splits "idproject__idcountry__name" into ["idproject", "idcountry", "name"]
    & follows finds the value of each foreign key relation
    """
    fields = field.split("__")
    if len(fields) == 1:
        return getattr(obj, fields[0], "")
    else:
        first_field = fields[0]
        remaining_fields = "__".join(fields[1:])
        return get_foreign_key_attr(getattr(obj, first_field), remaining_fields)
```

Comment: this is excellent, getattr should work like this!