# Access model's foreign key related fields using a string?

Tags: django, django-models

A similar question was asked here: [Access Django model's fields using a string instead of dot syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379249/access-django-models-fields-using-a-string-instead-of-dot-syntax)

I want to be able to access the value of a foreign-key related field in a django model, based on a dynamically generated string. For example, to get a direct field value you would use:

```
getattr(instance, 'name')
```

But I want to be able to follow foreign key relations, perhaps like so:

```
model_getattr(instance, 'name__othername')
```

This would require another query, and it might be possible to write the function model_getattr by splitting the attribute string on '__'. But I'm curious to know if there's a "correct" way to do this? Is it even possible?

UPDATE:

I managed to write a function that does what I need, but I would still like to know if there's a preferred way. This solution is obviously not as efficient as it could be, but it works for now:

```
def get_attribute(instance, name):

    if hasattr(instance, name):
        return getattr(instance, name)

    names = name.split('__')
    name = names.pop(0)
    if len(names) == 0:
        return None

    if hasattr(instance, name):
        value = getattr(instance, name)
        return get_attribute(value, '__'.join(names))

    return None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something which is already discussed in below thread

[How to get foreign key values with getattr from models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235807/how-to-get-foreign-key-values-with-getattr-from-models)

Comment: Thanks - I didn't see that question when searching :\

Comment: If your problem is solved using above link then please accept this as answer :-)